# Unix Editors to run and test ssh commands

Tags: linux, windows, unix, ssh, openssh

I am new to the world of Unix and would like to install some type of editor to run Unix ssh commands on my windows PC. If that is not possible then how can i go about practicing Unix commands? I would be making directories and storing data in them if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am reading you want to practice working in a unix command line on your windows PC.  Is this correct?

If so I might recommend you check out cygwin.
ref: http://www.cygwin.com/

cygwin can install on a windows machine and provide you with an emulated linux shell.  you can do pretty much anything basic you can do in linux in cygwin.

Comment: how do you install it I tried to I just want the basics

Comment: What do i choose for the packets?

Comment: There are a bunch of video tutorials explaining cygwin and installation / use.  A quick google gave me this one:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oImEq9JpF8Q#t=111

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two things which will enable you to use ssh:

1) If you want to keep on using Windows but have a remote machine on which you could login via ssh I recommend [PUTTY](http://www.putty.org/).

2) You can set up a virtual machine using e.g. [VirtualBOX](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think, running a Linux VM on virtualbox is a better choice. You have a complete system to play with.